# sending and receiving data to a CGI page from ASP .net webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, cgi

How can I send data from my .net web service to a CGI page and collect response?

It is an integration project.
One side (Client A) is collecting service requests in windows application + Sql server. another side (Client B) provides the services however they can accept the request from a cgi url http://mysite.com/cgi-bin/process.cgi (fake url).

Now I have to write a bridge (.net web service), which get initiated from windows app and submits data to the CGI url.

I am a novice web technician, detailed explanation is much appreciated.

e.g.
In an HTML page I can do like specified below

```
<form method="post" action="https://mysite.com/cgi-bin/process.cgi">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="acctid" value="TEST0">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Customer">
<input type="hidden" name="phnum" value="5454545454545454">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

How to do it in .net Web Service.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CGI is just an HTTP server extension. It solely depends on the server configuration which CGI to use for given request. So you can not directly call CGI - you call a HTTP server and server only then transmits a call to CGI and sets environment variables needed to complete request by CGI extension.